# How can I move elements from one array to another pseudo-randomly using a hash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random, hash

Picture two different arrays:

```
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let newArr = [];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is moving elements from `arr` to `newArr` via a pseudo-random loop, that attempts to mimic the functionality of `Math.random()`, except that the only randomness should go against a fixed, hash number.

I was trying something like this, but no luck so far:

```
const madeUpHash = "827354819373"
const floatIndex = "0."
const f = parseFloat(floatIndex + madeUpHash);

let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let ranNum = (f/i); // this points towards 0, meaning the next Math.Floor will eventually always retrieve index 0
    let rand = Math.floor(ranNum * arr.length);
    newArr.push(...arr.splice(rand, 1))
}
```

Not only does this not work, it's also pretty horrible.
Is there any reliable way to achieve this?
My other idea would be to loop through the individual digits of the hash (after transforming them into an array) and create a random number such as `ranNum = i/madeUpHash[i]` but that would break as soon as `i >= madeUpHash[i]` since it would return a positive integer bigger than one.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how people are implementing Math.random in javascript, but I know it in C.

Basically, the idea is, you got a hash function `hash`, and a seed `s`, you apply `hash(s)` to get your `X_0`, and for `X_(n+1)`, you do `X_(n+1) = hash(X_n)`.

As long as you choose a good hash function with the certain distribution you want for your randomness, it's very easy and consistent if the seed is the same.

For C, they are doing `Linear Congruential Generator`

```
X_(n+1) = (a * X_n + b) % m
```

So you can use your hash number as a seed and generate a series of pseudo-random numbers. Basically, you need a place to store your seed and replace it when you call the random generator (and don't forget to apply the hash function).

The randomness totally comes from your choice of hash function and it's not easy to prove you get a good hash function to generate random numbers (like we want a uniform distribution hash function in most cases, and the performance matters too). But I believe there is literature to do those proofs for you.

Comment: Interesting, so you use the result of the first hashing on the first iteration, pass that to the same function (rehashing the result of the first hashing), etc etc until you have your desired output?

Comment: @Ress It's not until you have your desired output, it's your output every time. Because it's hard to decide when you will get your desired output, so a good hash function should return results with enough randomness, this is purely a process of choosing the best hash function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random This page on section  `Random number engines`, you will be able to find different algorithms that C/C++ has implemented. I remember they are using a very large `a` and `c` in the C implementation

Comment: @Ress and found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator for section `Parameters in common use` it describes the values of `a` `c` `m` used in many implementations, hope this helps.

Comment: The hash function itself I already have, just didn't consider to implement it in the way that you mentioned. Whenever I get back on that I'll try this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Sanhu, I came back to this to say that your solution worked.  Thank you so much! Also I had an issue in the original code where the `arr.length` was changing due to the splice, which meant the execution stopped halfway through. Just had to save the original length in a variable beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you divide `ranNum` by i?

```js
let rand = Math.floor(f * arr.length);
```

Should be ok, because you decrease`arr.length` in each iteration. Also I'm not sure about incrementing `i` and removing an element from array, which affects the loop condition at the same time. Maybe just use the `while` loop.

Comment: Or set a variable to the original length, and use that in the iteration condition.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the value of `f*arr.length` isn't going to change by very much each time you decrement `arr.length`. It will just be the same as the previous iteration or 1 less.